# Error 404 Laravel, pero la ruta existe

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-8

La ruta existe, revise el route:list, limpie la cache de la ruta, pero aun me sigue apareciendo el error 404.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Esta es la ruta:

```
Route::get('cuentas/solicitudes',[CuentasController::class, 'solicitudes'])->middleware('auth.admin')->name('cuentas.solicitudes');
```

Funcion en el controlador:

```
public function solicitudes(Request $request){
        $agente = auth()->user()->agente;
        $cedula = $request->get('cedula');
            $cuentas = Cuenta::orderBy('cuentas.numero_cuenta', 'desc')
            ->join('clientes', 'clientes.id_cliente','=', 'cuentas.id_cliente')
            ->where('clientes.cedula', 'LIKE', "%$cedula%")
            ->where('estado_solicitud', false)
            ->paginate(10);

        return view('cuentas.solicitudes', compact('cuentas'));
    }
```

Esto esta en la plantilla nav:

```
<li><a href="{{ route('cuentas.solicitudes') }}">Solicitudes</a></li>
```

Comment: Si le sacas el middleware a la ruta, aún así te devuelve un 404?

Comment: Si. @porloscerrosΨ

Comment: La ruta existe, pero la vista? esta correcto el nombre? hicistes un dd() en el método para ver que llega al controlador?

Comment: Has probado:

php artisan route:cache